# How can I make the program read sensors every 10 milliseconds while the tcp server is waiting for data

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

My program need to read sensor data every 10 milliseconds, and send it to client by TCP socket. The program is written in C language. The tcp server and sensor reading codes are in the same c file. The server doesn't send data periodically. Instead, it waits for the data request (every 50 milliseconds) from the client. Once the server receives the request, it sends data to client.

My problem is that I need to read sensors every 10 milliseconds and save it in a buffer. Once the server get the request, send the sensor data in the buffer to client. But when tcp server is waiting for the request, the whole program stuck at the read function:

```
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,31)
```

Then, I can't read sensors.

I tried to use threading for sensor reading and tcp server. It works for reading sensors. But, if I add any usleep(), for example, 5 milliseconds in tcp server thread, it will take 5 milliseconds before sending data to the client.

My program need the tcp server send data to client immediately after it receives the request. Meanwhile, read sensors every 10 milliseconds. Anyone has a better solution?

The codes for tcp server and sensor reading are as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 256
#define SAMPLE_RATE 



void read_sensor(void) {
    printf("read sensors\n");
}


int main() {

     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno = 10000, clilen;
     char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     int data;

     printf( "using port #%d\n", portno );

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
         printf("ERROR opening socket\n");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
       error( const_cast<char *>( "ERROR on binding" ) );
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     while (1) {
        printf( "waiting for new client...\n" );
        if ( ( newsockfd = accept( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*) &clilen) ) < 0 )
            printf("ERROR on accept");
        printf( "opened new communication with client\n" );

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &gettime_now);
        start_time = gettime_now.tv_nsec;       //Get nS value
        while (1) {
             int n = 0;
             if ( (n = read(newsockfd,buffer,31) ) < 0 ) //read data
                printf("ERROR reading from socket");
             buffer[n] = '\0';

             if (n > 0)
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
             else {
                break;             
             }

             if ( (n = write( newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) ) ) < 0 ) //send data
                printf( "ERROR writing to socket\n");
             buffer[n] = '\0';

        }
        close( newsockfd );
     }


     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Allow each thread to operate independently of each other. The sensor reading thread should not need to interact with the client request thread.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to "immediately" make the transmission? Because everything up to 100ms can be considered "immediate" for the human eye. `while(1)` is a bad practice, make an obvious exit-condition, cover all the ugliness in higher level utilities so that the problem "pops up". Generally you can use `select()`-like functions to query as to whether there is data available. In my recent applications I actually used get_available_bytes sort of function. Consider your networking architecture very carefully.

Comment: Note that a bad network connection could lead to round-trip times longer than 10ms. Do you really need to deliver *all* sensor packets? Is it okay if some are dropped or delayed or out of order (and can be dropped by the receiver)? Then consider using UDP instead of TCP, as then you can just send the sensor packet and don't have to wait for replies.

Comment: The socket input queue IS a buffer, you can queue data there and receive in a thread, immediately when data is available (or delayed). Just make sure you header your packets so that the receiver knows what to expect.

Comment: `write( newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) )` is also problematic, as TCP connections are streams, with no preservation of packet boundaries.  If you're sending every 10 ms, and something happens over the connection, packets could get coalesced before they're read by the receiver and the data from multiple packets merged into one `read()`.  Packets can be merged if nothing bad happens.  And the string can be split into multiple packets, too.

Comment: Generally some of the best practices are to never send more frequent than you receive, always check send and receive values, always receive fixed-size packet that tells you at least two things ID and size of data to expect and perhaps use a queue that schedules sender's data in a predictable manner. You can have blocking receive (note timeouts) in thread or thread that calls async recv command when there is data available (see for e.g `select()`)

Comment: I can understand reasons why it might be important to sample a sensor at precise, 10ms intervals; but I would never attempt to _send_ the data over an internet connection on such a tight schedule. I would have one thread add a new sensor reading to a circular buffer every 10ms, and I would have another thread that maybe waits for some minimum number of readings to accumulate, then takes all the readings that are available in the buffer, then blasts them out together in a single message.

Comment: If my client told me, "No, you must transmit one reading every 10ms," then I would respond, "OK, that means we won't be using the internet. What other means of communication did you have in mind?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow That being said if he is looking for something close to real time data streaming, maybe check up RTMP. If it is something that requires immediate response I would never relay on internet too. In most cases a well-designed TCP protocol will do, but I don't know his target use case.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Easiest solution was mentioned above:  fire off UDP packets, with a one-up counter to ensure the latest packet is known.  An unsigned 64-bit counter should work - I'd love to be around to fix the bug should it ever roll over.  Have the receiver set an alarm that goes off if no packets are received in whatever time deemed "too long", and use QoS settings on the network to help prioritize packet delivery.  Because if it's that important, you'd better control the entire data path.

Comment: An example implementation of QoS is an async atomic singly-linked list with a sort function, counter and priority integer, alongside recursive threaded send and recursive threaded receive. I personally use GAsyncQueue and threaded polling.

Comment: @Edenia Yeah, I'm doing the realtime plotting. I use c/c++ to read sensor data and plot it with python.  All these codes are on the same raspberry Pi. The reason I used TCP socket is that I need to send data from c file to python. I'm not sure if there are better ways to do it rather than send data by the socket.

Comment: @TingWang Is there any particular reason you want to use Python and not just C for everything, which would have been better for performance and portability? I've only programmed on Arduino, which is much more lacking in processing power than the Raspberry Pi, but from what I understood you want to achieve IPC between two processes. If I did not understand you correctly you want to use C code alongside Python or the opposite. If that's the case check out Python extension modules, which can be used to include C code. I have no clue about Python development on Raspberry Pi though.

Comment: For IPC, using sockets on the LAN is one way to do it. However there is much more going on, than what is needed. Let alone the packet's protocol header overhead, the kernel resources involved, the subsystem which manages the transport layer interface. A binary file direct I/O is another easy way to achieve IPC. In most cases it may be slower than socket io, but not always. If file already exists on disk, is not large, is binary it is fairly competitive even faster.

Comment: @Edenia  The reason I used python is that I designed a GUI with PyQt4 for real time plotting. But you know python cannot do very fast and precise sampling (e.g. 
 > 200 Hz), so, I used c/c++ to do it. Then I send data from c to python by tcp socket. I know it's not a good way to do it. But I don't know a better solution. The client wants everything in a raspberry Pi.

Comment: @TingWang I suspected it must be the GUI. Python has very rich GUI toolkits. But you could've done that in C with GTK+ as well or with C++ Qt. Anyway 3rd IPC method I can think of is message queuing if supported by system API and of course pipes.

Comment: @Edenia I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: @Edenia Hi Edenia, I tried select and poll, then I realised that if there is a tcp socket connection, both these 2 functions will stop timing. Unless I close the socket connection. That's not good. Because I cannot open and close a connection each time the client wants to send request to the server. Because the request frequency is 20 Hz. The open and close operation will decrease the frequency. Maybe I should try binary file direct I/O you mentioned above.

Comment: @TingWang It seems to me that you misunderstand how those functions work. Did you read their man pages? Sometimes I have trouble understanding even though I read it, because of language barriers and stuff (I am not english myself). Now I don't use much winsock (or unisock) - I use GSocket and other higher level APIs. The GSocket wrapper to `select()` will block until timeout is reached or input/output (whatever I specify) streams are readable/writable (videlicet if there is data). I find it for much more convenient to query pending bytes (see `ioctl`), because of the nature of my protocol.

Comment: Just get pending bytes in your receiver thread and if there are > 0 bytes recv data. If you are sending fixed-size packets every time it's easy just check if pending bytes `== sizeof(struct packet)` and recv that many bytes.

Comment: I would say neither methods are absolutely 100% reliable. They will work, but every system is prone to errors such as race conditions,kernel panics and so on. Some operations predisposes OS to fail more than other. It is really of essence that you design your program in such a way that this is avoided as much as possible and that if something fails, it is expected and it can recover. The latter is especially important for file io, where checking return values is mandatory and proper handling may prevent race conditions.

Comment: Alternatively see named pipes, D-BUS and this: https://www.engineersgarage.com/embedded/raspberry-pi/how-to-send-message-between-processes-using-signal-in-raspberry-pi because there may be easier and more reliable ways to achieve this. Although I wouldn't use C(++) and Python for something like this or for everything for that matter anyway.

Comment: @Edinia Thank you so much for all these helps. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`select`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to wait for data to arrive, with a timeout.

For instance, if you need to read the sensor 5 milliseconds from now, you can call `poll` or `select` with a 5 millisecond timeout. If the socket receives data, it will return immediately and tell you. Otherwise, it will return after 5 milliseconds and you'll know there is no data.

Example with `poll`:

```
struct pollfd pollfd = {.fd = socket_fd, .events = POLLIN};
int err = poll(&pollfd, 1, milliseconds_timeout);
// error check here; if err is negative then the error code is in errno
if (pollfd.revents & POLLIN) {
    // Socket received data
}
// Otherwise it didn't.
// Note that if data was received, it might not be time to read the sensors yet.
// You should keep poll()ing until it's the right time to read the sensors, using clock_gettime to check the time.
```

Comment: Hi immibis, quick question- if the socket gets the data before the 5 milliseconds is out, will the poll() continue until it reaches 5 milliseconds or start a new counting?

Comment: Neither, it returns. You can also use ppoll if you need a more precise timeout.